# Django: Running site on many languages

Tags: django, internationalization

I want to run an article site on several languages, I already translated translation strings, so my templates are ready. I only have a questions how to store articles in many languages? Should I create a database for each translation or it works in different way?

If I have for example this basic model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    models.TextField()
```

And want to store data in many languages, how do I do it? How to organize redirects between one article on different languages

Comment: @Oleg: see this project http://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl/src/tip/docs/usage.rst for examples of encoding locale into URL's

Comment: This is an up-to-date project that should solve your problem: https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple approach to this problem is to add a "language" field in each model which identifies the language used for each record.  This seems to be the approach used by [django-pluggable-model-i18n](http://code.google.com/p/django-pluggable-model-i18n/).

Another approach is to use Python metaclasses to identify fields for translation, as used by [django-translate](http://code.google.com/p/django-translate/) and [django-transmeta](http://code.google.com/p/django-transmeta/).

There are several other projects but many of them seem abandoned or lower quality.  Django-transmeta always seemed the most interesting to me.

**Edit**: muhuk just wrote an excellent article today reviewing different translation projects: http://www.muhuk.com/2010/01/dynamic-translation-apps-for-django/

Answer (score 1):

There is also: [django-multilingual](http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual/)

Comment: This project is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how folks at django-cms solved this problem- you can also get your hands dirty and extract the portions of code that are responsible for nice multilingual urls  (e.g. url http://site.com/en-us/some_view/ routes correctly to some_view/ and sets request.LANGUAGE_CODE to en-us).