# The best/recommended way to translate Django database values

Tags: database, django, internationalization, translation

I'm trying to figure out the best way to translate actual database values (textual strings, not date formats or anything complicated) when internationalizing my Django application. The most logical ways I could come up with were to either:

- hold a database **column** for every language (e.g. `description_en`, `description_de`, `description_fr`, ...) or
- have a different **database** for every language (e.g. `schema_en`, `schema_fr`, `schema_de`, ...).

Are these the best options, or is there something else I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: also, this is a really small and simple app with perhaps 5 or less tiny tables.

Comment: Is every installation supposed to have 1 single language, as opposed to have a language setting per user?

Comment: the app supports language selection per user, so it must support all implemented translations in a single instance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984327/django-running-site-on-many-languages

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was reading up on my django extensions, and found the [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) plugin. It seems to do exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: looks good at first glance, I'll have to play with it a bit - thanks!

Comment: I'm coming late on this one to suggest a new solution for db translations, yawd-translations - github.com/yawd/yawd-translations. It allows to manage languages through the admin interface (at runtime) and implements an admin inline to easily manage translations. Since I'm developing for yawd I use a comment instead of a new answer not to be accused for self-promotion :)

Answer (score 5):

I also found this [small project](https://github.com/ecometrica/django-vinaigrette) which purpose is to synchronize localized strings into standard message files for fields of registered models.

Example:

```
import vinaigrette
vinaigrette.register(YourModel, ['name', 'description'])
```

The standard command

```
$ manage.py makemessages
```

Would maintain messages for each distinct values found in registered fields.

I have not had the occasion to try it yet.
But this seems for me to be the simplest way to translate data from db.

Comment: This means each time you add a new record in the database, you may have to re-run makemessages and check in po files if there's a new entry... just a warning. But anyway, this is what I was looking for, it's lighter than django-modeltranslation which adds a column in the tables that need translation for *each* language...

Answer (score 1):

“Easily translate “cheese omelet” into “omelette du fromage”.
django-parler provides Django model translations without nasty hacks.

https://django-parler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/