# How to translate object attributes in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible make translations for Django objects?

Let's say I have model `Category` and `Product`. When user adds new product, they have to choose from `Category` objects. I would like to translate those names.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Category'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('Categories')

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('Company'), related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('Name'),)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', verbose_name=_('Category'), related_name='products')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Product')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Products')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.name)
```

So before running the server, I create couple of categories like 'Electronics'.

What should I do to make name 'Electronics' translated to name 'Elektronika' for SK language?

Comment: Does this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030653/2689986), answer your question?

Comment: You mean you want to translate user entered inputs?..

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil It seems good, I will try it.

Comment: @Sayse No user entered, but kind of.. admin creates a categories with names in english and I want to translate those names, somethink like there was: english_name, czech_name, german_name etc in the Category model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best/recommended way to translate Django database values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019364/the-best-recommended-way-to-translate-django-database-values)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you put `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _` in the models.py. Next thing to do is set language and locale settings to `settings.py`

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('tr', ugettext('Turkish')),
    ('fr', ugettext('French')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),

)
```

After that you must put `'django.template.context_processors.i18n',` into your context_processors in the `settings.py`. If you do all of that, all you have to do is run the following commands in terminal;

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=tr
django-admin compilemessages --locale=tr
```

When you do that django will create folder called locate into your project directory. Inside of the locale directory, you will see language codes that you apply makemessages into. [image]

Inside that you can edit `django.po` files. django.po file will be look like this.

```
msgid "Content"
msgstr "İçerik"
```

After you translate "Content" to "İçerik"(in Turkish), you should do `makemessages` and `compilemessages` again. After that whenever django sees "Content" while your site language is in Turkish(in this example), it will render it to you as "İçerik".