# Django - best practice for translating and organizing enumeration-type data structures

Tags: django

Let's consider a model:

```
class MobileContact(models.Model):
    contact_type = ....
```

So we have to model mobile contacts and each contact has a type (like work number, mobile number, email, fax, pager) etc.

At first, I organized the code the following way:

```
class ContactType(ChoiceEnum):    
mobile = 1
work = 2 
home = 3    
work_fax = 5
home_fax = 6
email = 7

class MobileContact(models.Model):
    contact_type_id = models.IntegerField(ContactType.choices())
```

This approach has an advantage of the following code pattern:

```
contact_values_qs.filter(contact_type_id = ContactType.email.value)
```

This pattern has pros and cons:

Pros:

- Good code readability (`contact_type_id = ContactType.email.value` is much nicer than `contact_type_id = 7`)

Cons:

- If I have to see the enumeration values in user interface, I don't have string representations, not to mention inability to translate these strings

So I rewrote the code in a standard way:

```
class MobileContact(models.Model):
    contact_type = models.ForeignKey(ContactType, ...)

class ContactType(models.Model):
    type_name = CharField(...)
```

**THE QUESITON:**

1. How do I translate the values of `type_name`? I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019364/the-best-recommended-way-to-translate-django-database-values), but the latest supported version of python is 3.4. My project deploys 3.5
2. How do I structure the code when selecting `contact_types` to maintain code readability.

For example, I want to select `work` and `work_fax`. The only way I know to do this is:

```
contact_types = ContactTypes.objects.filter(id__in = [2,5])
x = MobileContact.objects.filter(contact_type__in = contact_types)
```

...but I think this is very poor code in terms of readiblity in part of `id__in = [2,5]`.

Any help on this?

Comment: For the #1 question, [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) is your one-way road. I use it with Python 3.5 with absolutely no issues.

Comment: Ok. Thank you much for this